# DNS server with api access

Tags: dns

Experts, i have a requirement and wanted to find a tool that will be helpful for me.

We have a inhouse tool, that will help developers request/lease a VM for a short duration of time. When the VM is assigned, i send the developer an email with details of the VM and the application details. I currently use xip.io to send a fully qualified DNS name. Something like this

https://omni.54.84.86.26.xip.io

https://auth.54.84.86.26.xip.io

https://mgmt.54.84.86.26.xip.io

This works well, but the feedback that i got from my developers is ,

```
The url is very hard to remember

Everytime is request for a VM i get a new URL and i cant bookmark it. it keeps changing everytime.
```

I think their concern is valid. One idea to solve this is to create a per defined DNS names with username in it like

omni-prajan.myorg.com

admin-prajan.myorg.com

mgmt-prajan.myorg.com

where prajan is the username. So everytime i request for a vm, i need to programmatically modify IP that is associated with this domain name in my dns server. We are using AWS now.

Is there a better way to handle this requirement?

Comment: Depends a lot on how your instances are built, but creating a route53 record along with the machine using cloudformation or terraform sounds very straighforward

Comment: +1 for Route53. If you ever move off AWS, or want something else, it sounds like a job for [Consul](https://consul.io)

Answer (score 1):

Route53 [has an API for creating DNS records](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/APIReference/API_ChangeResourceRecordSets.html).  The API is a bit obtuse, but there are a plethora of wrappers for various languages.